# Finding the biggest area object from binary mask using cv::findContours fails, because contour is not closed. How to prevent that?

Tags: c++, opencv, contour

I am trying to perform dark (almost black) object detection in video source based on its shape features (ex.: area, contour length etc.), but I have problem with detection of contours in binary mask.

Sometimes even though the object doesn't change shape and contour is derived from a simple mask containing only one compact blob, the contours is not closed (I can tell that, because I am displaying it with CV_FILLED option, and for many frames the contour is filled), and because of that calculated area is not actually trustworthy (value lowers down to several pixels).

I also noticed, that when contour of object is not closed, the length is about 2 times greater than supposed to be (which makes sense).

Why are contours of simple blobs sometimes open and sometimes closed and how I can force them to be always closed? I already tried convex hull, and also copying the first point of contour to its end, but it didn't work.

The steps of my approach are following:

1. Convert image to grayscale
2. Perform thresholding, erosion and dilation to remove noise and improve "shape"
3. Use Canny edge detector do get only edges
4. Use findContours to get contours, and their areas:
5. Use arcLength to calculate length of contours and other features.

Comment: Instead of explaining it, put some "problematic" images and the code you used

Comment: Why do you use Canny edge detector? Using findContours on the shape would work no?

Comment: @Miki: I couldn't put images, because I don't have enough reputation on SO. Hugo: I don't know why, but on my computer (VS2012+Opencv2.4) findContours crashed the program even though I used it on the proper image (black and white result of thresholding operation). Strangely, it worked on result of Canny detector, but with problems.

Comment: Put them on some public place like imgur and share public link

Comment: Nothing we can do without code and images...

Answer (score 0):

> 3. Use Canny edge detector do get only edges

That's a classic mistake. After and during step 2 I assume you have a binary image, i.e. a black image with a bunch of *filled* white blobs that denote the areas you want to find. **That is exactly what `cv::findContours` works on.**

When you do edge detection you actually transform those nice filled regions into a bunch of very thin long and *possibly but not necessarily* closed lines bounding your former areas, which messes everything up. Thus `cv::findContours` will return exactly that, a bunch of very thin contours. Those contours *are* actually closed, too, in that they represent a closed polygon with the last point connecting back to the first one, just that this polygon *wraps around* those thin lines resulting from edge detection, which explains why their area is very small and the perimeter about double what you expect. It basically treats those lines resulting from edge detection *not* as the actual contours, rather than the very thin *areas* you want to find the boundary contours of, which is likely not what you intend.

*If* those boundary lines are closed *and* you only retrieve the outer contours (e.g. with `CV_RETR_EXTERNAL`), you *might* get about the same proper area contours you expect, but that is just not guaranteed and is easy to mess up.

So the simple solution is to just **drop the Canny Edge Detection step and work on the proper binary image directly**, as `cv::findContours` is *usually* intended to.